# Getting access token for CURL/Browser Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to obtain messages and attachments from Facebook, I'm using:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/message.getThreadsInFolder?access_token=AT&folder_id=0
```

To get the list of threads and:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=AT&q=QUERY
```

For my queries.

But, every time, I copy the access token generated by the Graph API Explorer as I don't seem to be able to get it programmatically:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET
```

Gives me an access token, but it doesn't work. If I try to use it with the URLs above I get:

```
"error_msg":"A session key is required for calling this method"
```

And for the second one:

```
  "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 190
```

The Facebook documentation it's really unclear.

I do not want to use a login flow, is there a way to login programmatically with the stored credentials as the mobile application does?

Comment: grant_type=client_credentials is wrong. See either https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/ for details on how to get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

You need a login flow which you are not using (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/). It is not possible to get a user access token programmatically. This defeats the point of manual user interaction. The user must explicitly grant access to your application.

Comment: If I need to login every time I want to use my application, how comes that the mobile applications don't need a browser login everytime?

Comment: @Uno they do login, it's just not visible the second or third time it happens

Comment: How can I do the same thing, then?